# TableView on UIViewController with array information

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview

Hi I am trying to use a tableview on my uiviewcontroler
on my .h I put this code:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

and on my .m:

I modify my code but now it says my Response_array is undeclared and also myTablevView not found on object type uitableviewcell

```
@synthesize myTableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [_responseArray count];
}
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] init];
}
NSString *cellValue = [_responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];
 return cell;
}
```

Here is my Response_array

```
NSArray* Response_array = [json objectForKey:@"avenidas"];
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: on the -(UITableViewCell *)myTableView line

Comment: -(UITableViewCell *)myTableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath                   will not be called and will cause an error because the delegate method is declared incorrectly. It should be -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   Also, check to make sure you have a beginning and ending bracket { } before and after the method body.

Comment: thanks that work but now I have other errors

Comment: @darkjuso, No problem! I'm glad that helped. I've provided an answer below.

Comment: @Jon thanks, I don't have errors anymore but the tableview doesn't show anything, maybe I forgot something

Comment: The apple developer site has a page on UITableViews and explains everything in detail. You should be able to find your solution from reading through it and also learn a great deal. Other than that, it might be the connection through a storyboard (an IBOutlet connecting the delegate and datasource to the ViewController) or how you are populating data (the array which contains the objects of type). http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: @Jon, thanks yes I forgot to connect the delegate and datasource but I am getting __NSCFDictionary isEqualToString on the line [cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];

Comment: @darkjuso, I'm not completely sure why you are getting that error, but "Because the JSON parser returns an autoreleased object, your [responseArray] is getting deallocated on end of scope. -retain it." – H2CO3. Also, take a look at the selected answer. Referenced from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878412/nscfdictionary-isequaltostring-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x6b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem: Response_array is undeclared**

In your `@interface` file create a property that declares your NSArray

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray * responseArray;
```

In your `@implementation` file `@synthesize` the property

```
@synthesize responseArray = _responseArray;
```

---

**(Optional)**

In `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You can use the tableView parameter to access the tableView instead of the myTableView property.

Example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

---

**Problem: myTablevView not found on object type uitableviewcell**

```
cell.myTableView = cellValue;
```

You are trying to access a tableView within your cell? The UITableViewCell has a default label called textLabel.

So it should be as follows (unless you have a custom Label):

```
[cell.textLabel setText:cellValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a *nested* method there.

In other words, you have a method that is essentially:

```
- (IBAction)Avenida:(id)sender {

    -(UITableViewCell *)myTableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    }

}
```

No wonder your code isn't compiling.

You need to extract your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" method **out** from your "`Avenida`" action method.  These should be two separate methods.

Comment: I put the cellForRowAtIndexPath out still getting the "Invalid argument type UITableViewCell to unary expression" error

Comment: I manage to put it out and now I modify my original post with a new error

Comment: so now you have a new problem?  This would be a great opportunity to post a separate and new question. :-) In any event, I am glad I was able to help you out with solving the first problem.  In which function is your "`Response_Array`" declared?  You should make it an instance variable (i.e. put it in your "`@interface`" .h file).